# Material for melting metal oxides

Tags: experimental-chemistry, materials, reactivity

I am constructing an apparatus for high temperature, strong alkaline melts (metal melts), with extremely high oxygen rich environments.

Here what I have so far.

Iridium is a good candidate - is it better as an alloying agent or would it suffice in an almost pure Iridium composition?

Tantalum - has good temp but from what I understand is weak against alkaline reactions. 
If nothing else gets answered, could this please. 
If I have a tantalum oxide layer coating the tantalum will that protect it from further corrosion in a high temperature, oxygen rich environment?

Tungsten seems to also have potential, I remember reading a paper from the 50's stating that under high alkaline, temperature conditions the product contained an unsuitable level of impurity from the tungsten? with the properties of tungsten would this be the case.

What I am enquiring about here does anyone know what metals or alloys off-hand that are currently used in these conditions?
Basically I am only looking at refractory metals as the temperature range is (1900 deg C - 2900 deg C)
Also there can be no carbon in the composition of the alloy.

Comment: You seem to have three questions that are somewhat related.  Is there something that you are really curious about or trying to do, that you are asking questions to try and solve?  This feels like it could be could be a [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I am trying to create a crucible for melting corundum and other metal oxides at the temperatures specified. Need a vessel to handle the heat and oxygen without corrosion

Comment: Sometimes I think the XY "problem" should be defined as "when an arrogant person refuses to answer the question asked because they think the question is not worth answering." – Aaron McDaid May 1 '16 at 11:07 
This is ment as a joke. :-)

Comment: It's not even arrogance, it's about asking about " asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem."  I don't know nearly enough to answer your question, but I'd imagine that if you asked directly about what you wanted to do, and outlined your ideas, you might get a solution, not necessarily what you envisioned.  Something along the lines of, "Crucible material for high temperature metal oxides" or something.  Then again, you may very well get the solution you are looking for here, I don't know.  Best of luck, either way!

Comment: I did do a brief search, and it's unfortunate about your carbon requirement, because apparently there are crucibles that would deal with the temperature and pH requirements. I'm guessing you already eliminated vitreous/glassy carbon crucibles.

Comment: my apologies about the comment I just found it funny I understand what you are saying and my comment centralised my question.

Comment: yes unfortunately I have looked at those. Most Insulators at this temp have carbon. its basically your refractory metals and their alloys. thank you for taking the time to respond, it is appreciated.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/how-do-you-melt-metals-with-super-high-melting-points

Comment: Why do you want to melt them?

Comment: I actually asked someone I know that worked with high temperature melts, but for crystal growing, and they said that iridium or platinum crucibles may work.  Either as a material would be very expensive, but it depends on what your budget is.  Both have the melting temperature that you need, and I believe that platinum may be the cheaper option of the two.

Comment: Thank you for that fyrepenguin. What industry is he in? What crystals do they grow sapphires per chance?

Comment: platinum has a melting point of around 1600 deg C but iridium or an alloy containing iridium may be best.