# Reforging tungsten/tungsten carbide temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, phase, melting-point, metallurgy

I was wondering about the reforging of tungsten and the temperature needed.

As I understand it, tungsten melts at $\pu{3442 ^\circ C}$ and tungsten carbide at $\pu{2870 ^\circ C}$. However, once a jeweler makes the rings they will never take them back to alter them.

Does the temperature needed to melt a pure tungsten ring change after the initial forging (with all heat treating and cooling included) or is there no change?

If there is a change:

1. What temperature is needed for tungsten?
2. What temperature is needed for tungsten carbide?
3. What atomic/chemical changes took place?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/how-do-you-melt-metals-with-super-high-melting-points

Comment: Avoid asking multiple questions at once please.